# Sinon chai negative assertions not working with expect

Tags: mocha.js, sinon, sinon-chai

I'm trying to use sinon-chai with expect but when I try to check if a function is not called, I get:

```
TypeError: expect(...).to.have.not.been.called is not a function
```

This is what I tried:

```
  expect(createCompany).not.to.have.been.called();
  expect(createCompany).to.not.have.been.called();
  expect(createCompany).to.have.not.been.called();
  expect(createCompany).to.have.been.not.called();
  expect(createCompany).to.have.been.notCalled();
```

But none of them is working, but I have no problem without the ".not"

My file is starting with:

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const sinonChai = require('sinon-chai');

chai.use(sinonChai);
const { expect } = chai;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I found that this is because of the parens.
So just replace called() by called and it's working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a spy with expect:

```
expect(spy.called).to.be.false
```